# In which order are CSS styles applied?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>asdas</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my CSS stylesheet I have general settings for the a tag, and several hundered lines later settings for ul li a.
Like this:

```
a:link
{
 color: red;
}
...
ul li a
{
 color:blue;
}
```

Firebug tells me, that first the color:blue is loaded, and afterwards overriden by color:red
So far I've always thought, that the order of loading css files and the order of style inside a single css file tell the browser how html elements should be formatted. Unfortunately I'm now experiencing it vice versa.

So tell me, how must I correct my style to achieve the a tag inside the li to be rendered blue and not red?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the spec behavior for two conflicting CSS styles from an external file?  How well do browsers support this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819410/what-is-the-spec-behavior-for-two-conflicting-css-styles-from-an-external-file)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Styles are applied according to which styles are most *specific* to the element; among rules that have equal [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the *last* matching rule in the CSS text wins. (There's also a new concept of "layers" I won't go into here.) More [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html). Because `a:link` is more *specific* than `ul li a`, that style wins regardless of placement.

For the purposes of calculating specificity, the browser (and other tools that process CSS) use numbers with three columns:

- Column 1: The number of ID selectors
- Column 2: The number of CLASS selectors (and similar), such as `.class` (a class selector), `:hover` (a pseudo-class selector), and attribute selectors like `[type=button]`
- Column 3: The number of TYPE selectors, like `a` or `ul` as well as `::before` and such

Each column is more significant than the one after it (just like in decimal numbers, where in the number `123`, the `1` is more signfiicant than the `2`, which is more significant than the `3`).

`a:link` comes out as 0-1-1 because it doesn't have any ID selectors, has one class selector (`:link`), and has one type selector (`a`). `ul li a` comes out as 0-0-3, because it doesn't have any ID or class selectors, but has three type selectors. 0-1-1 is more specific than 0-0-3 because the leading 0s are the same, but 0-1-1 has a 1 in the second column where 0-0-3 only has a 0 (so we ignore the third column, since the second column is more significant than the third).

> So tell me, how must I correct my style to achieve the a tag inside the li to be rendered blue and not red?

Make the blue rule at least as specific as the red rule. In this case, you can do that by adding `:link` to it:

```
ul li a:link {
    color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's an article about CSS Selector specificity which looks good: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

The section in **How to measure specificity?** gives you the answer:

```
a:link   => one tag (a) + one pseudo-class (:link) = 1 + 10    = 11 points
ul li a: => three tags (ul, li, a)                 = 1 + 1 + 1 =  3 points
```

So the a:link style wins.

Hint: Order (in the CSS files) only matters when two css selectors have the same specificity.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use `color:blue !important;`

Comment: There are two problems with this. First, you got the syntax wrong (the bang comes before the word important). Second, it is the sledgehammer approach and there is no coming back. If you have a third style you want to put into the cascade, then !important is going to knock it over too.

Comment: @David Dorward Thank you, I corrected it. I was just answering to his question `So tell me, how must I correct my style to achieve the a tag inside the li to be rendered blue and not red?` was I not, he didn't say anything about third style did he now :D Its very ugly I agree but it answers his question

Comment: Can downvoter tell me why the downvote, I fixed the syntax error, what else must I fix/explain/or not