# CSS class targeting

Tags: html, css

Just a quick one if anyone would be so kind. I'm baffled as to why I **sometimes** need to use an ancestor selector in order to effectively target a CSS class.

For instance, if I'm trying to hide an element with class `.mobile-hide` in a media query stylesheet:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child1" class="social-icon">Facebook</div>
        <div id="child2" class="social-icon mobile-hide">Twitter (Hide Me)</div>
        <div id="child3" class="social-icon">Instagram</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use simply:

```
.mobile-hide { display:none; }
```

in my stylesheet it does nothing. But when I use:

```
#container .mobile-hide { display:none; }
```

it works as expected and I cannot understand why.

Comment: This information is available elsewhere and is much better described here than any answer anybody can give you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Could be the specificity of the rule. Do you have other CSS rules that could be overriding that one?

Comment: Style Precedence in CSS http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Thanks guys. The style precedence / specificity factor was the key here. Adding an `!important` rule solved the problem for me.

Comment: @BenClarke - `!important` is something you should try hard to never have to use in CSS, so this is the wrong way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `display` style set on `.social-icon` which is overriding the display for `.mobile-hide`.  If you specify the container for `.mobile-hide`, then that style will take precedence over `.social-icon` since it is more specific.

Comment: Many thanks Mike. Your answer helped me understand what was happening. You were right in that it's initial display style of `display:inline-block` was taking precedence. By adding an `!important` rule after the `display:none` it worked as expected. I know using `!important` is sometimes not recommended, but it seems to be fitting for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have some other styling that has higher precedence in the first case. Precedence is based on specificity.

Here is some further information on the matter that may be useful:
[In which order are CSS styles applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826368/in-which-order-are-css-styles-applied)

Comment: Link provided for convenience. According to you simply removing the link makes it answer instead of a comment. If you really want to be nitpicky then you should just mark this as a duplicate.