# Which selector will apply for HTML tag

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
     .divNav
     {
        font-size:25px; 
     }

     #divNav
     {
        font-size:25px; 
     }
</style>

<div class="divNav" id="divNav">
```

Both ID and class have same style.

Which will apply? And what is the reason?

Comment: the last one, since the id selector has higher specificity. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: try to research on `css specificity`

Comment: As @fcalderan says the ID. As an ID can be used only once in a page it will hold a higher specificity

Comment: Check the selected as answer reply of this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826368/in-which-order-are-css-styles-applied

Answer (score 0):

It will always apply id style. Because Id have high specificity .

Check:

```css
#divNav
       {
        font-size:25px; 
       }
.divNav
       {
        font-size:15px; 
       }
```

```html
<div class="divNav" id="divNav">test</div>
```

And:

```css
.divNav
       {
        font-size:15px; 
       }
      
#divNav
       {
        font-size:25px; 
       }
```

```html
<div class="divNav" id="divNav">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.divnav{
  color:red !important;
  }

#divnav{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class='divnav'  id='divnav' style='color:yellow'>Test</div>
```

You can try to remove important and style in tag for look at the priority.

Css have some priority :

> - Tag < class < id
> - Style in attribute > id
> - But **!important** > all, don't use it

you can calculate priority using :

```
Style in attribute = 1000

#id = 100

.class = 10

tag = 1
```

So

```
#id .class tag {
 /* = 111 */
}

#id #id2 {
/* = 200 */
}
```